# MonoGame: SpriteFont: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The content file was not found

Tags: c#, xna

In the Title you can see my problem. I set everything which need, but I still get this error, when I want to use a Content.Load method. In the constructor I set RootDirectory:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

[image]

After that, I want to use the Content.mgcb where I created a Score.Spritefont, see below in the picture.

[image]

In the code I write this:

```
spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Score");
```

When I reach this line in the code I got this error message: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The content file was not found.

I stack here and I didn't find solution. Please somebody help me.

Comment: Have you run the build in the contentmanager?

Comment: Yes, I run the build.

Comment: Anybody can help?

Comment: Anybody please help me?

Comment: When you do a build, it turns your content into .XNB files. Can you search and confirm if the Score.xnb file is getting generated? I don't remember the exact path, but I think it will be under the bin directory somewhere.

Comment: @britter Thanks a comment i'll search in the future.

Comment: @britter It generated yeah!